# Why assign value to UIView transform property in sequence?

Tags: iphone, ios, view, transform

While reading sample code, I found some code about orientation change. The interesting part is that *transform* property of *self.view* is assigned with value in sequence. Logically, it seems the first assignment doesn't take any effect since it is overwritten by following assignment.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait == toInterfaceOrientation) 
    {
        self.view = portraitView;

        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(0));

        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == toInterfaceOrientation) {
        self.view = landscapeView;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(-90));

        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    } else {
        self.view = landscapeView;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(90));

        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    }
}
```

The doc says the method *willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation* is called before orientation animation actually takes place.

So, the assignment to *self.view.transform* is actually working like pushing value to a stack? or how does Cocoa Touch know that the view should be first set to *CGAffineTransfrmIndentity* then to another value?

Comment: I agree, those lines assigning the identity matrix seem to be pointless. Where is this sample code from?

Comment: From source code of the book <Beginning iOS 5 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK> at http://iphonedevbook.com/

Comment: OK, well they made a mistake. That happens. I would report that to them so they can correct it. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, identity transform doesn't do anything on its own. So double assignments here are pointless.

BTW: Samples from Apple use only single assignments:
[GKTank sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTank/Listings/Classes_TankViewController_m.html)